# Get Charge Object Data Returned From Stripe Checkout

Tags: php, stripe-payments

My app is using `PHP 8.1.2`, `Stripe`

For a couple of weeks now I've been trying to learn a bit about using `Stripe` in a `PHP` app. I've looked and threads and short tutorials, but there is so much to learn.

I followed an online video to add a one-item checkout to my PHP site. A user submits a registration form and gets taken to Stripe's credit card payment page to complete the process. After paying, the user is redirected back to my site.

The tutorial stopped there and did not offer any info on retrieving data from `Stripe` after the checkout was complete.

Is there a way to get information from Stripe about the `charge object` (a term I saw online) when the user is returned to my site? I would like to be able to store the `charge object id` in a database for future needs.

My Code:

```
// my checkout.php code

// vars used in $session block come from submitted form

// my database connection
require_once('../includes/db_connect.php');

// stripe files/classes
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// my stripe keys
require_once('../includes/stripe-keys.php');

// set the Stripe api key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key_live);

// session that goes to stripe
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
       'currency' => 'usd',
       'product_data' => [
         'name' => 'Summit-2024',
       ],
       'unit_amount' => $price,
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => "https://www.livingmuaythai.com/events/success.html?name=$full_name&email=$email&payment_option=$payment_option&event=$event",
  'cancel_url' => 'https://www.livingmuaythai.com/events/summit.html',
]);

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KxD8J8CAFg
// $session->url will take the user to the Stripe checkout page
//
http_response_code(303);
header("Location: ". $session->url);
```

In the docs on https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges, I see `THE CHARGE OBJECT` example:

```
{
  "id": "ch_3MmlLrLkdIwHu7ix0snN0B15",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 1099,
  "amount_captured": 1099,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_3MmlLrLkdIwHu7ix0uke3Ezy",
  "billing_details": {
    "address": {
      "city": null,
      "country": null,
      "line1": null,
      "line2": null,
      "postal_code": null,
      "state": null
    },
    "email": null,
    "name": null,
    "phone": null
  },
...
```

Is there a way to get this info from `Stripe` on my `success.html` page after a transaction?

If Yes, could you provide me an easy to understand example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Webhook Endpoints.  I found this about an hour after I posted my question/problem.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints

Stripe will even give you the code template to use to capture the endpoint objects.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement a webhook endpoint that listens to the `checkout.session.completed` event. In the webhook event handling code, you should retrieve the checkout_session object with `payment_intent` [expanded](https://stripe.com/docs/expand), so that you can get charge object through `checkout_session->payment_intent->latest_charge`